# Scrapy ImportError: No module named 'settings'

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape some data from a website and want to store it into postgree database, but i'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'settings'

My Tree view for the folder is:

```
Coder
├── coder_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── livingsocial.py
├── output.json
└── scrapy.cfg
```

Spider code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from coder_app.items import CoderItem
# from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class LivingsocialSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "livingsocial"
    allowed_domains = ["livingsocial.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        # deals = response.xpath('//li')
        for deal in response.xpath('//li[a//h2/text()]'):
            item = CoderItem()
            item['title'] = deal.xpath('a//h2/text()').extract_first()
            item['link'] = deal.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            item['location'] = deal.xpath('a//p[@class="location"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['price'] = deal.xpath('a//div[@class="deal-price"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['end_date'] = deal.xpath('a//p[@class="dates"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Pipeline.py is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from coder_app.models import Deals, db_connect, create_deals_table


class CoderPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class LivingSocialPipeline(object):
    """Livingsocial pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_deals_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save deals in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """
        session = self.Session()
        deal = Deals(**item)

        try:
            session.add(deal)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

Model.py code is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


def db_connect():
    """
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


def create_deals_table(engine):
    """
    Performs table creation
    """
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Deals(DeclarativeBase):
    """Sqlalchemy deals model"""
    __tablename__ = "deals"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    link = Column('link', String, nullable=True)
    location = Column('location', String, nullable=True)
    #original_price = Column('original_price', String, nullable=True)
    price = Column('price', String, nullable=True)
    end_date = Column('end_date', DateTime, nullable=True)
```

and settings.py is:

```
BOT_NAME = 'coder_app'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['coder_app.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'coder_app.spiders'

DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': 'mohib',
    'password': '100200',
    'database': 'scrape'
}
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'coder_app.pipelines.LivingSocialPipeline': 300,
}
```

Why i am getting this error, also I have tried

```
code_app.import settings
```

in model.py but then I got this error:

```
NameError: name 'settings' is not defined
```

I'm really stuck here. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried `from code_app import settings`?

Comment: works like charm! Thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import settings
```

write

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
```

and then inside a function or method:

```
settings = get_project_settings()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had one problem like this because i had a python module with the same name of my project.

Try to run pip uninstall with your project name.